# Can't get google maps autocomplete to honor country restrictions

Tags: jquery, django, jquery-ui, python-2.7, google-maps-api-3

I have been trying to get the google autocomplete withn a django template to only search in my own country. Autocomplete works. I am als getting current position OK. Results of autocomplete are always around the world, no matter what I try. My code this far is:

```
$('#map_canvas').gmap( {'center': '52.251963, 5.296059', 'zoom': 8});
$('#map_canvas').gmap().bind('init', function(evt, map) {
$('#map_canvas').gmap('getCurrentPosition', function(position, status) {
  if ( status === 'OK' ) {
     var clientPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,     position.coords.longitude);
     $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', {'position': clientPosition, 'bounds': true});
  }
});
});

var auto_options = {
types: ['(cities)'],
componentRestrictions: {country: "nl"}
};


$('#map_canvas').gmap('autocomplete', 'locality', 'auto_options',function(ui) {

    });
```

Answer must be quite simple I suppose but I can't find it. Hope someone knows.

Regards, Berend

Comment: remove the quotes from `'auto_options'`

Comment: Unfortunately removing the quotes makes no difference.